# emacs prelude in malabar-mode for java:"Cannot open load file:semantic/db-javap"

Tags: emacs

it complains "Cannot open load file:semantic/db-javap". What's that and where can I find it.I googled but can't find any useful hint.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you haven't installed CEDET as per the malabar-mode instructions:

- Clone https://github.com/alexott/cedet/tree/devel

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/alexott/cedet.git
  make all
  ```

I think the correct clone URL for cedet these days would be http://git.code.sf.net/p/cedet/git and not the one given there.